# Using list vs div for gallery like items display

Tags: website-design

I'm making a webpage for the company i'm working in, and I've been tasked with creating two display for items in content (it's a search result display page):

Gallery and List.

The thing is that I've used divs, but seen in Google images that they're using unordered list for displaying results.

I'd like to know if there's any advantage of using list instead of divs like I did.

Thanks a lot.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/USX34/

Expand the HTML result so you can see clearer.

Thanks a lot.

PS: I have posted question here but I'm not certainly sure that it's the right place, but I think it will be closed if posted i

Comment: A list of items makes sense to display it as list rather than divs. It is only semantics of the markup language. There's no technical advantage choosing one over the other, although it's good practice to use lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images are part of a set of items, and a list is more semantically appropriate, as noted in the comments.

Have a look at the way the excellent [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (version 2) handles groups of [thumbnails](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails):

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Version 3 of Twitter Bootstrap I believe would mark require it to be marked up differently.

Comment: A little off-topic and admittedly I can't see the bigger, but why repeat the same class on every contained `li` and `a` when all the styling can be controlled by the class on the `ul`?

Comment: @w3d I can't speak for the Twitter Bootstrap team, but the source can speak for itself: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/thumbnails.less I expect it's to allow specific hover behaviors, and allow flexibility as to what contains the thumbnails (either `<a>` or `<div>`. If you have a better idea, fork the TwBootstrap code! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with using unordered `<li>` lists you have the option to setup jQuery plugins which can sort and filter the lists. If you create dynamic ID's or Classes on each list element you can work with them even more. It's better than using just `<div>` tags.

Comment: That's ok though it's the same answer and mine was posted first ;)